# Jackson date format issue : java bean to JSON string conversion

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am converting a java bean to JSON string using Jackson 2.7.4 version. In doing so, I am facing date format issue. Java 1.7 version is being used.

**Bean :**

```
public class BaseBean {

    private java.util.Date fromDate;

    public Date getFromDate() {
        return fromDate;
    }

    public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
    }
}
```

and I am **getting below date format**

```
{"fromDate":1465370289436}
```

Which is not required by me. then I **configured below code**

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS , false);
jsonInString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objJava);
```

Then I am getting **below date** format in JSON :

```
{"fromDate":"2016-06-08T07:47:06.636+0000"}
```

**Expected date format :**

```
{"fromDate":{"date":8,"day":3,"hours":12,"minutes":48,"month":5,"seconds":9,"time":1465370289436,"timezoneOffset":-330,"year":116}}
```

Is there any configuration to handle it and get expected date format in JSON string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**JSON date Serializer :**

```
public class CustomDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

@Override
public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {

    // below methods of Date object is deprecated - consider this as sample example 
    int idate = date.getDate();
    int day = date.getDay();
    int hours = date.getHours();
    int minutes = date.getMinutes();
    int month = date.getMonth();
    int seconds = date.getSeconds();
    long time = date.getTime();
    int timezoneOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
    int year = date.getYear();

    jgen.writeStartObject();

    jgen.writeNumberField("date", idate);
    jgen.writeNumberField("day", day);
    jgen.writeNumberField("hours", hours);
    jgen.writeNumberField("minutes", minutes);
    jgen.writeNumberField("month", month);
    jgen.writeNumberField("seconds", seconds);
    jgen.writeNumberField("time", time);
    jgen.writeNumberField("timezoneOffset", timezoneOffset);
    jgen.writeNumberField("year", year);

    jgen.writeEndObject();      
}

@Override
public Class<Date> handledType() {
    return Date.class;
}
```

}

**Setting serializer in SimpleModule :**

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonInString = "";
    try {
        SimpleModule myModule = new SimpleModule();

        myModule.addSerializer(Date.class, new CustomDateSerializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(myModule);
        jsonInString = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(objJava);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e1) {          
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope this will help !

Answer (score 0):

You can add methods to your class to get:

- date
- day
- hours
- minutes
- ...

For example

```
private DateFormat hoursDF = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");

public String getHours() {
    return hoursDF.format(fromDate);
}
```

Comment: this approach is not feasible for me. Could you please advise other solution for same.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate with JsonSerialize. It may be possible to override serialize method of JsonSerializer.

Comment: @JsonSerialize (using = MySerializer.class) 
private java.util.Date fromDate; 

class MySerializer extends JsonSerializer<T> { 
Override
public void serialize(T value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException 
{  
gen.writeString(//whatever format is required here...)
}
}
}